# Is there a way to populate an ImageList using images online?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I am trying to get some pictures and load them onto a `ListView` as icons so I can select multiple of them. I need an `ImageList` for the `ListView`, but I couldn't find a method to provided URLs for the images for the `ImageList`, the way a `PictureBox` does.

What's the best way to read these images into an `ImageList`?

Comment: Of course some kind of loop is needed

Comment: Download the image from the URL to an app data folder and then load it from there

Answer (score 3):

You can do this(the links i choose some car pictures randomly):

```
List<string> adress = new List<string>(){"http://www.diseno-art.com/news_content/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/2013-Jaguar-F-Type-1-600x399.jpg"
                                         ,"http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02351/Jaguar-F-type-9_2351861k.jpg",
                                          "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02351/Jaguar-F-type-5_2351885k.jpg",
                                          "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02351/Jaguar-F-type-7_2351893k.jpg"};
    ImageList il = new ImageList();
    foreach (string img in adress)
    {
          System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(img);
          System.Net.WebResponse resp = request.GetResponse();
          System.IO.Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
          Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(respStream);
          respStream.Dispose();

          il.Images.Add(bmp);
     }
```